# Remove string before slash, Objective C

Tags: objective-c, regex, cocoa

I need help in regex in string:

> /folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder5/folder6/folder7/ololo/ImageName.png

I need to match:

> ololo/ImageName.png

How do you do that in Objective-C?

Comment: Read the NSString spec, especially the stuff near the bottom of the function list about path manipulation.

Comment: Why would you use a regex for that?

Comment: well if you follow your question title then it should match `ImageName.png` not `ololo/ImageName.png` - please can you explain the  desired output clearer?

Comment: Does it need to be regex? There is a simple non-regex solution.

Comment: Alex Coplan - I'm work woth path, not work with image name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you do it with regular expressions:

```
NSString *path = @"quick/brown/fox/jumps.png";
NSError *error;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"[^/]+[/][^/]+$" options:0 error:&error];
NSRange rangeOfMatch = [regex rangeOfFirstMatchInString:path options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, path.length)];
NSLog(@"From %d, length %d", (int)rangeOfMatch.location, (int)rangeOfMatch.length);
```

This code finds `fox/jumps.png`

Comment: thanks, this code return "From 12, length 13", but a need NSString

Comment: @Sergey You need to use `[path substringWithRange:rangeOfMatch]` to get your string.

Comment: Thank's All, my imagination has helped :). I used [path substringWithRange:rangeOfMatch]

Answer (score 1):

To match the string.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = nil;
predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES 'ololo/ImageName.png'"];
if (![predicate evaluateWithObject:@"/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder5/folder6/folder7/ololo/ImageName.png"]) 
{
// do your work here.. 
}
```

Comment: folder names that I do not know, I know 3 last name folders

Answer (score 0):

You can match the sting with this -

```
if ([@"/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder5/folder6/folder7/ololo/ImageName.png" rangeOfString:@"ololo/ImageName.png"].location != NSNotFound) 
{
   //true
   // do your work here
}
```